# Trying to get an alertdialog to change textview based in chosen option

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-alertdialog

I want the dialog to show the correct text based on the selected option (ie. If pressed TWO I want is to show the text "you pressed TWO")

on the first press it seemingly does nothing the text goes to the initialized
on the second press you find out the text was switched to default

I'm new to android and I don't think I understand what the activity is doing here.
Can someone please help me find a way that works?

```
public class AndMainT extends Activity {
private GameLogicT myGame = new GameLogicT();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b_com = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b_com.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CharSequence[] pick_one = {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE"};
            call_menu(pick_one);
            updateAwesomeText();
        }
    });
}

public void updateAwesomeText(){
    TextView newText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    newText.setText(myGame.getCurrent_opt().getDescription() + "\n");
}

public void call_menu(CharSequence[] items){
    final CharSequence[] f_items = items;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Orders Captain?");
    builder.setItems(f_items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            myGame.startOpt(item);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
}


public class GameLogicT {
class GOpt{
    private CharSequence description = "this is the intialized text sadface";

    public CharSequence getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(CharSequence description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

private GOpt current_opt = new GOpt();

public void startOpt(int item){
    switch(item){
    case 1:
        current_opt.setDescription("you pressed ONE");
    case 2:
        current_opt.setDescription("you pressed TWO");
    case 3:
        current_opt.setDescription("you pressed THREE");
    default:
        current_opt.setDescription("I am a fart and think you have pressed nothing sadface");
    }
}

public GOpt getCurrent_opt() {
    return current_opt;
}
public void setCurrent_opt(GOpt current_opt) {
    this.current_opt = current_opt;
}
}
```

I also tried

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        CharSequence[] pick_one = {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE"};
        call_menu(pick_one);
        try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        updateAwesomeText();
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        myGame.startOpt(item);
        notify();
    }
```

This causes a force close when the button is pressed, it's not my question just saying I tried!

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I can't test your code due a lot of work.
However,after taking a look I noticed the following:

1) I think that position of items starts from index 0.
2) Maybe you lost some `break` in the `switch-case`statement

So, try to replace it with:

```
public void startOpt(int item){
  switch(item){

    case 0:
       current_opt.setDescription("you pressed ONE");
    break;

    case 1:
      current_opt.setDescription("you pressed TWO");
    break;

    case 2:
      current_opt.setDescription("you pressed THREE");
    break;

    default:
      current_opt.setDescription("I am a fart and think you have pressed nothing sadface"); 
  } 
}
```

Hope it helps you!